# what is the complexity of this code snippet?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a question in regards to the time complexity of the below code. I am guessing that the time complexity is, **O(n^3)** but my friend told me that the time complexity should be **O(n^2)**. However, I am still not convinced with the answer. My stand is that:　the first and second for loop would cost **O(1/2 n^2)** and inner loop would need another some O(n) complexity. Therefore, it is about **O(n^3)**.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= len; j++) {
        int mid = (i + j) / 2;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            dist[i][j] += Math.abs(A[k - 1] - A[mid - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your friend's reasoning behind n^2

Comment: Note that O(n²) ⊂ O(n³), so you could both be right.

Comment: he said that the second loop is i+1, so the second loop would loop O(1/2n^2) times, but he did not account the last loop.

Comment: @SIRO1690 Forgive him. It is infact O(n^3).

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag in what circumstances it could be O(n^2)?

Comment: If something is O(n x n) then it is also O(n x n x n).

Comment: If you can't do the sums correctly yourself, Wolfram alpha can compute the number of loops exactly: `sum(sum j-i+1, for j=i+1 to n), for i=1 to n`. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sum+j-i%2B1,+for+j+%3D+i%2B1+to+n),+for+i+%3D+1+to+n

Comment: thanks Raman,jorg, pencils and paul.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to find the time complexity of something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= N; j++) {
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
            // some O(1) operation
        }
    }
}
```

Each of the loops run in O(N), so the complexity is O(N^3). You can also write a simple test program in your language (I wrote in python):

```
def check(N):
    s = 0
    for i in xrange(1, N + 1):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, N + 1):
            for k in xrange(i, j + 1):
                s += 1
    return s

print [check(i) for i in xrange(1, 10)] // [0, 2, 7, 16, 30, 50, 77, 112, 156]
```

And checked for a [closed form for this sequence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=closed%20form%200,%202,%207,%2016,%2030,%2050,%2077,%20112,%20156). It is [image],

which is clearly **O(n^3)**